# Difference between Digital Rights and Satellite Rights?

Tags: production

What is the difference between Digital Rights and Satellite Rights? Or are they the same? What are the factors affecting the average cost for them?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Movies & TV. That can be a good question, but the last part is difficult to answer and can make your question too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Drop the second half of the question and this should be answerable, I think.  The difference between digital and satellite rights should be fairly objective and clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Digital rights are the rights bought from the production company by a franchise to use their content (music, movies, art etc.,).

Quoting from [this](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24928/digital-rights) page:

> Digital rights refers to the relationship between copyrighted digital works (such as film, music and art) and user permissions and rights related to computers, networks and electronic devices. Digital rights also refer to the access and control of digital information.

This includes many including video games, computer software, E-books, music on internet(release on YouTube and other websites).

But satellite rights only refer to television rights. Satellite rights are well explained in [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17556/what-is-satellite-rights-in-indian-movie-industry/17557#17557) answer  by [@AnkitSharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma).

According to that answer,

> Satellite right is the legal permission given by the producer of a film to a Television channel to show (broadcast) the film in TV. It might be for a limited time period or for lifetime. There will be many clauses and conditions like the film can be shown in TV only after a particular time period etc.

Hence we know that satellite rights and digital rights are not same. We can say satellite rights is a subset of Digital rights.

**What are the factors affecting the average cost for them?**

This is also explained in that answer(in case of Indian movies. But it will be similar in any film industry.). This is not same for every movie. It depends on many factors.

> - Cast.
> - Production Banner (Yashraj production can sell its films on higher rate to channels than any new production house).
> - Past record of the people associated with the film.
> - Success or expectation of the film.

It also depends on the buzz it creates before the release. The cost will be high if the film is a blockbuster.